# Proper use of MediaQuery in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

What is the best practice for using MediaQuery? The app will be used in different screen sizes, so hard-coding the width and height of a widget might be a problem.

I'm having a hard time understanding the different uses of the MediaQuery class. I  tried searching for it online, but I didn't find many examples. It would be great if anyone can help me to understand this class or can provide a link that I can use to understand this MediaQuery class.

Comment: Yes try to avoid static height. MediaQuery is for getting certain aspects of the screen but you should combine also with AspectRatio when necessary. Also consider more dynamic layout widget such as Flexible, FitBox, Expanded, Stack and so on.

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-for-multiple-screen-sizes-and-orientations-in-flutter-fragments-in-flutter-a4c51b849434

Answer (score 4):

A few points there will be:

- For instance, `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` - will not give you the exact width in pixels for your physical device measurements but rather in logical pixels. To get the exact physical device measurements you need to do something like this: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio`

  - `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top` is the height of the status bar
  - `kToolbarHeight` is the height of the AppBar
  - in case you have a BottomNavigation bar, the height is `kBottomNavigationBarHeight`.

So, to deduct all the values above, we can do like this: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height — MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top — kToolbarHeight — kBottomNavigationBarHeight`

I've put this tutorial together some time ago, if you are still looking for an answer to your question. [Widgets sizes relative to screen size in Flutter using MediaQuery](https://medium.com/tagmalogic/widgets-sizes-relative-to-screen-size-in-flutter-using-mediaquery-3f283afc64d6?source=friends_link&sk=ecb1073d657f271df4e84d1b67c968bb). I hope it helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25133211)

Comment: Edited the above for more guidance.